Interpreting letters from cld output from emmeans R
I normally assign the letters for pairwise comparisons of the estimated marginal means manually.  However, I wanted to use cld from multcomp as an alternative.  I tried on a smaller dataset; however, the output from cld is not what I was expecting, and I am unsure if my code is incorrect or if I am interpreting it incorrectly.
fit1 <- lm(formula(paste("log(",trait2,")", 
            "~ Time + SEX + AGE + Farm"), sep=""), data=test_data)
modelb <- emmeans(fit1, c("Farm","Time"), type="response")
multcomp::cld(modelb, Letters = LETTERS, alpha=0.05)

 Farm  Time  response    SE df lower.CL upper.CL null t.ratio p.value .group 
 FarmA Day30     4.23 0.792 42     2.90     6.17    1   7.701  <.0001  A     
 FarmA Day0      4.50 0.843 42     3.08     6.57    1   8.030  <.0001  A     
 FarmC Day30     4.58 0.810 42     3.20     6.54    1   8.602  <.0001  A     
 FarmC Day0      4.87 0.861 42     3.41     6.96    1   8.951  <.0001  A     
 FarmA Day7      4.96 0.930 42     3.40     7.24    1   8.555  <.0001  ABCD  
 FarmC Day7      5.37 0.950 42     3.76     7.68    1   9.507  <.0001  A     
 FarmD Day30     5.77 1.308 42     3.65     9.12    1   7.738  <.0001  A C   
 FarmD Day0      6.14 1.391 42     3.89     9.70    1   8.010  <.0001  AB  E 
 FarmD Day7      6.78 1.535 42     4.29    10.70    1   8.444  <.0001  ABCD  
 FarmE Day30    12.47 2.366 42     8.50    18.28    1  13.294  <.0001   B DEF
 FarmE Day0     13.26 2.516 42     9.04    19.44    1  13.619  <.0001    CD F
 FarmE Day7     14.63 2.776 42     9.97    21.45    1  14.137  <.0001      EF

Results are averaged over the levels of: SEX 
Confidence level used: 0.95 
Intervals are back-transformed from the log scale 
Tests are performed on the log scale 
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 12 estimates 
significance level used: alpha = 0.05 
NOTE: If two or more means share the same grouping symbol,
      then we cannot show them to be different.
      But we also did not show them to be the same. 

However, if I look at the significant pairwise comparisons, this does not make sense:
df1<- data.frame(pairs(modelb))

for (i in 1:length(df1$p.value)){
if (df1$p.value[i]<0.05){print(paste("Significant result for ",df1$contrast[i], "with a p-value",round(df1$p.value[i],6)))}}

[1] "Significant result for  FarmA Day0 / FarmE Day0 with a p-value 6.8e-05"
[1] "Significant result for  FarmA Day0 / FarmE Day7 with a p-value 0.000187"
[1] "Significant result for  FarmA Day0 / FarmE Day30 with a p-value 0.000992"
[1] "Significant result for  FarmC Day0 / FarmE Day0 with a p-value 1e-06"
[1] "Significant result for  FarmC Day0 / FarmE Day7 with a p-value 2.9e-05"
[1] "Significant result for  FarmC Day0 / FarmE Day30 with a p-value 0.000248"
[1] "Significant result for  FarmD Day0 / FarmE Day0 with a p-value 0.000534"
[1] "Significant result for  FarmD Day0 / FarmE Day7 with a p-value 0.001497"
[1] "Significant result for  FarmD Day0 / FarmE Day30 with a p-value 0.008278"
[1] "Significant result for  FarmE Day0 / FarmA Day7 with a p-value 0.001435"
[1] "Significant result for  FarmE Day0 / FarmC Day7 with a p-value 0.000399"
[1] "Significant result for  FarmE Day0 / FarmD Day7 with a p-value 0.011948"
[1] "Significant result for  FarmE Day0 / FarmA Day30 with a p-value 0.000277"
[1] "Significant result for  FarmE Day0 / FarmC Day30 with a p-value 4.8e-05"
[1] "Significant result for  FarmE Day0 / FarmD Day30 with a p-value 0.002249"
[1] "Significant result for  FarmA Day7 / FarmE Day7 with a p-value 6.8e-05"
[1] "Significant result for  FarmA Day7 / FarmE Day30 with a p-value 0.002627"
[1] "Significant result for  FarmC Day7 / FarmE Day7 with a p-value 1e-06"
[1] "Significant result for  FarmC Day7 / FarmE Day30 with a p-value 0.000869"
[1] "Significant result for  FarmD Day7 / FarmE Day7 with a p-value 0.000534"
[1] "Significant result for  FarmD Day7 / FarmE Day30 with a p-value 0.02159"
[1] "Significant result for  FarmE Day7 / FarmA Day30 with a p-value 9.6e-05"
[1] "Significant result for  FarmE Day7 / FarmC Day30 with a p-value 1.3e-05"
[1] "Significant result for  FarmE Day7 / FarmD Day30 with a p-value 0.000743"
[1] "Significant result for  FarmA Day30 / FarmE Day30 with a p-value 6.8e-05"
[1] "Significant result for  FarmC Day30 / FarmE Day30 with a p-value 1e-06"
[1] "Significant result for  FarmD Day30 / FarmE Day30 with a p-value 0.000534"

Based on these results, I would have assigned to following letters to the pairwise comparisons (Farm A, C, and D would get A for every timepoint and Farm E would be assigned a B).  I then created the following graph (estimated marginal means with 95% confidence interval)

Am I wrong in how I have been assigning the pairwise comparison manually or is my interpretation incorrect?  I realize that letters from cdl are saying the Farm E is significantly different then the other farms on all time points but I just don't understand how it is also not the different or the same by also being assigned letters C, D, and E

One issue is that your plot is displaying a compact letter display for Farm | Time, whereas your code is asking for the cld for Farm * Time.
I'm also wondering if something is getting a little tricky with the log transformation being in the formula itself instead of the dependent variable being log transformed in the data.  And then the type=response option.  You might just try log transforming the dependent variable in the data, using this as the dependent variable, and see if the output is different in terms of the letter assignments.
As a final note, be sure to pay attention if the pairs() or cld() results have a p-value correction applied for multiple comparisons.  Usually emmeans automatically applies that correction (as stated in your results), which will be different if you making fewer comparisons, like in the Farm | Time case.
